# Suppose $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{g(t)}{t}= 1$, $g(0)= 0$, determine $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{ x^2 +[g(y)]^2}{[g(x)]^2+y^2}$ if the limit exists.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

The problem is the following:

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{g(t)}{t}= 1$, $g(0)= 0$, determine $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{ x^2 +[g(y)]^2}{[g(x)]^2+y^2}$ if the limit exists.

A classmate of mine in the calculus class gave this exercise to me, and I've been stuck on this exercise for a few days. Intuitively, the limit $\lim_{t\to 0} g(t)/t =1$ tells us that asymptotically $g $ has exactly the order of $t$ as $t\to 0$. So we may expect that the limit actually approaches to the same limit as:
$$
 \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2} = 1.
$$
However, I have no idea how to rigourously approach the problem. I've also noticed that the hypothesis also implies that $ \lim_{t\to 0} g(t)/t  =\lim_{t\to 0} [g(t) - g(0)]/t = g^{'}(0) = 1$, but this seems to lead me to nowhere. I would like to ask how to solve it. Does the limit exist? Or there's a counterexample to this limit? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In polar coordinates, the limit is

$$\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta+g^2(r\sin\theta)}{g^2(r\cos\theta)+r^2\sin^2\theta} =\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{\cos^2\theta+\frac{g^2(r\sin\theta)}{r^2}}{\frac{g^2(r\cos\theta)}{r^2}+\sin^2\theta} = \lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta} = 1$$

uniformly for all $\theta$. Therefore the whole limit is $\boxed{1}$.

Comment: Since $\theta$ is not fixed, $$\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{\cos^2\theta+\frac{g^2(r\sin\theta)}{r^2}}{\frac{g^2(r\cos\theta)}{r^2}+\sin^2\theta} = \frac{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta} $$ makes no sense.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have re-edited Ninad Munshi) answer adding $\lim_{r\to 0^+}$ symbol  (I hope Ninad doesn't mind. Now it makes sense.

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you explain why $\theta$ not being fixed is a problem in this particular limit?

Comment: And @RyszardSzwarc your modification makes it seem like the terms involving the function $g$ (which carry the $r$-dependence) disappear out of nowhere while the limit $r \rightarrow 0^+$ has not been taken yet. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Edd When $r\to 0$ the expression $g(r\sin\theta)^2/r^2$ is equal  $\sin^2\theta + o(r).$ Similarly $g(r\cos\theta)^2/r^2 =\cos^2\theta +o(r).$  So we can skip both $o(r).$ I agree that the answer could be still made more clear.

Answer (score 3):

We have $g(t)=th(t)$ with $h(0)=\lim_0h=1.$ For every $(x,y)\ne(0,0),$
$$\begin{align}\left|\frac{x^2+[g(y)]^2}{x^2+y^2}-1\right|&=\left|[h(y)]^2-1\right|\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\\&
\le\left|[h(y)]^2-1\right|
\end{align}$$
hence
$$\lim_{(x,y){\longrightarrow\atop\ne}(0,0)} \frac{ x^2 +[g(y)]^2}{x^2+y^2}=1.$$
Similarly,
$$\lim_{(x,y){\longrightarrow\atop\ne}(0,0)}\frac{[g(x)]^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}=1.$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{(x,y){\longrightarrow\atop\ne}(0,0)} \frac{ x^2 +[g(y)]^2}{[g(x)]^2+y^2}=1.$$
Note that we didn't need to assume the existence of this limit: we proved it.

Comment: If $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ then $y=0$ is allowed and you encounter a problem with the first limit.

Comment: As Ryszard pointed out, you should write that $\text{if }\,y=0\,\text{ then }\;\left|\dfrac{x^2+[g(y)]^2}{x^2+y^2}-1\right|=0\;,$
$\text{whereas if }\,y\neq0\,\text{ then }\\\begin{align}\left|\frac{x^2+[g(y)]^2}{x^2+y^2}-1\right|&=\left|\frac{[g(y)]^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\\&\le\left|\frac{[g(y)]^2-y^2}{y^2}\right|\\&=\left|\left(\frac{g(y)}y\right)^2-1\right|\;.
\end{align}$

Comment: Fixed my way, thanks @Ryszard.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to omit application of the polar coordinates (although I am a great fan of them) in the following way. Let
$$h(t)=\begin{cases} {g(t)^2\over t^2}-1 & t\neq 0\\
0 & t=0\end{cases} $$
Then $\,\lim\limits_{t\to 0}h(t)=0=h(0)\,$ and
$${x^2+g(y)^2\over g(x)^2+y^2}= {x^2+[h(y)+1]y^2\over [h(x)+1]x^2+y^2}={1+h(y){y^2\over x^2+y^2}\over 1+h(x){x^2\over x^2+y^2}}\quad (*)$$
We have
$$0\le |h(y)|{y^2\over x^2+y^2}\le |h(y)|,\quad 0\le |h(x)|{x^2\over x^2+y^2}\le |h(x)|$$ hence both ratios showing up in $(*)$ tend to $0.$ Thus the limit is equal $1.$

Comment: @Edd Thanks. I will re-edit.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers given are great, nothing really to add. But just for the sake of completeness, I would like to write down an argument by definition. Though it's not very practical, it's an excellent exercise.

First, for any $0 < \varepsilon < 1/2$, we show that the function
$$(x,y) \mapsto \frac{g^2(x)-x^2}{x^2+y^2}$$
is bounded by $\varepsilon$ in a neighborhood of $(0,0).$ For this, we consider $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\left| \frac{g^2(x)}{x^2}-1 \right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \qquad \text{ for all } 0 < |x| < \delta,$$
which we can do because $\lim_{t \to 0} g(t) / t = 1.$ Now, if $0 < \lVert (x,y) \rVert < \delta$ and $x \neq 0$ we have
$$\left| \frac{g^2(x)-x^2}{x^2+y^2} \right| = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\left| \frac{g^2(x)}{x^2}-1 \right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon.$$
In particular, this means that
$$\frac{1}{1 + (g^2(x)-x^2)/(x^2+y^2)} < \frac{1}{1-\varepsilon} < 2,$$
which also holds even if $x = 0.$

With this auxiliary result, whenever $0 < \lVert (x,y) \rVert < \delta$ we have
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{x^2+g^2(y)}{g^2(x)+y^2} -1\right| & = \frac{\left|(x^2-g^2(x))+(g^2(y)-y^2)\right|}{(g^2(x)-x^2)+(x^2+y^2)} \\
& \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \, \frac{x^2+y^2}{(g^2(x)-x^2)+(x^2+y^2)} \\
& = \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \, \frac{1}{1 + (g^2(x)-x^2)/(x^2+y^2)} \\
& < \varepsilon.
\end{align}

The above shows that
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+g^2(y)}{g^2(x)+y^2} = 1.$$
Just as a reminder, the fact that we choose $0 < \varepsilon < 1/2$ is not detrimental to our argument, it never is.
Finally, note that we don't need to specify $g(0)$, as is usual with limits. We just care about the local behavior of the functions in a neighborhood of the point of interest.